# Equal Height not working in Safari (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari, equals

```
$.fn.equalHeight = function () {
    var height = 0,
        reset = $.browser.msie ? "1%" : "auto";
    return this.css("height", reset).each(function () {
        height = Math.max(height, this.offsetHeight);
    }).css("height", height).each(function () {
        var h = this.offsetHeight;
        if (h > height) {
            $(this).css("height", height - (h - height));
        }
    });
};
```

.. works great in Firefox and even the crappy IE6 but not Webkit (Safari, Chrome). How do I fix it?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://webkit.org/blog/66/the-fouc-problem/

Comment: Equal heights doesn't work in webkit, works in all other browsers.

Comment: Same problem here...only Chrome and Safari as you said...the column heights are equal thought, but the content of one column overflow...It looks like it is getting the wrong height as the max height...

Comment: Here is a snapshot of mine with the blog feeds overflowing the column...are the blog feeds loaded AFTER the `equalHeight()` is executed? I call the script in the footer though, with a proper `jQuery(document).ready()` but it still does not work. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a5987p87

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to load your script with `jQuery(window).load()`, it solved my problem.

Read more [here](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Comment: Adding 'jQuery( document ).ready(function()' also fixed it for me.